# Getting the font size of a Menu Item in the Win32 API?

Tags: winapi

Is it possible to retrieve the size of the font used in a menu via the Win32 API?  I have found the `GetTextMetrics()` call, but cannot find a way to specify it getting the font used in a menu.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can use this call

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS)
```

to get various system parameters.  The resulting structure contains a [LOGFONT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms901140.aspx) item for the menu font and you should be able to determine the fontsize from that.